# Exclude only first post on tag x from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm searching to exclude only the first post on an specific tag on Wordpress, using the `PHP Array`, because actually it excludes all post from that tag. Actually I have this code (I show only the PHP code, because the HTML code for the structure is irrelevant here):

```
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;
wp_reset_postdata();
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'posts_per_page'         => 8, 
    'post_type'              => 'post',
    'cat' => '14',
    'tag__not_in' => array( 157 ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

global $wp_query;
// Put default query object in a temp variable
$tmp_query = $wp_query;
// Now wipe it out completely
$wp_query = null;
// Re-populate the global with our custom query
$wp_query = $the_query;
```

I was trying with `'offset' => 1` but didnt worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Imagine I have 8 post on the category of the example (14), and 3 of them have the tag 157 (of the example). I want to show the 8 post and if any of them have the tag 157, exclude the newer published one with that tag (or the most recent modified date)

Comment: It seems like the offset should be the right answer.

Comment: But didn't worked for me, I don't know here insert him, you can make a reply with the modified code inserting the offset and we see if works or not.